# in which order will ubuntu search bin-folders for executables?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

So I learned that in order to be able to execute a program from everywhere in the shell I have to put a reference file looking something like
         #!/bin/bash
         path/to/my/original/executable 
in my bin-directory and make it executable.

On my current linux system (provided by my workplace) there are multiple bin-directories like
    /usr/local/bin
    /home/MyUsername/bin/
    /home/otherUsername/bin/ 
For my work I have to alter a c++ program which is supposed to be usable for every user on the computer (hence I used /usr/local/bin/ sofar). But I realized that my changes to the original program do not come through... So my questions are:

1. Where could other bin-folders be, that I need to check for old executables?
2. How does my operating system (ubuntu 16.04) choose between executables in different bin-locations but with the same name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/386629/what-are-the-default-path-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH` shell variable contains a colon separated list of paths to look for executables in. The list is processed left to right, the shell executes the first executable binary it finds (make sure to `chmod +x` the binary you are providing). If you want an easier printout you can use: `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"`. Also keep in mind that a program might have been started with a different `PATH` than your shell and that users can customize their `PATH` variable. Systemwide `PATH` settings can usually be found in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/`. You can use `which file` to display the full path expansion of `file`.